# What is the difference and/or similarity between multiple universes in inflation and in quantumphysics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, cosmology, quantum-interpretations, multiverse

Some theories propose that there are [more universes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiverse).

In one of them it is said that there are parallel universes, due to inflations after the big bang that created them.

But in the two-slit experiment is also known the multiverses theorie. The probability wave is not collapsing but each possibility is creating a universe on his own.

So they both speak about other universes. But is there a link between them? Or are that just completely different things/theories?

Comment: The link is that neither of those theories has anything to do with actual physics or the real world.

Comment: I believe that Max Tegmark considers them being qualitatively different (and perhaps both 'real'), but part of a single theory. http://space.mit.edu/home/tegmark/home.html and http://www.internationalskeptics.com/forums/showthread.php?p=9864224#2462

Comment: If I recall correctly the inflationary ones are just too far apart for them to be observable from the others... And perhaps that there are so many of them, that some/any of them must have practical twins?! (Maybe I'm just making this up.)

Comment: Define "parallel universe" without philosophical waffling, please.

Comment: At this point you can throw every book and text that mentions "parallel universe" into the recycling bin. It was a waste of paper to print it.

Comment: There exists at least one paper, 2011 Bousso-Susskind, that claims that the many worlds of inflation and many worlds of Everett both  exist and they are the same: http://inspirehep.net/search?ln=en&p=find+a+bousso+and+a+susskind&f=&action_search=Search -  https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.3796 -  I am confident that that most of their peers believe that this notion is completely wrong, as I do. Everett's many worlds are just a superfluous ideological superstructure, using the words of Heisenberg, while inflation is a part of physics that may be right and can't be replaced by another "interpretation".

Answer (score 2):

The inflationary theory you mention is probably [eternal inflation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_inflation). In this theory there is just one universe but different parts of it are causally disconnected i.e. the different parts cannot affect each other in any way. Whether these constitute a multiverse comes down to terminology. In principle there is a continuous spacelike straight line that links any two points in the *multiverse*, so I would not describe this as separate universes.

The theory you mention in connection to the two slits experiment is the [many worlds interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation) of quantum mechanics. However the physical reality of the *many worlds* is a contentious issue. So once again whether this really counts as multiple universes is a matter of opinion.